# Do we often say "to feel itchy on + a part of a body", for example: "I feel itchy on my nose"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request

> [itchy](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/itchy?q=itchy) (adj): ​having or producing an itch on the skin
>
> an itchy nose/rash
>
> I feel itchy all over.

---

Most dictionaries say "**I have an itchy nose**", "**My nose is itchy**" or "**I feel itchy**"

But, no dictionary that has this kind of examples "**to feel itchy on + a part of a body**"

For example: "**I feel itchy on my nose**"

Although, I saw many results when searching "**[itchy on my](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22itchy%20on%20my%22&oq=%22itchy%20on%20my%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.5232j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)**" on the internet.

Is it idiomatic to say "**I feel itchy on my nose**"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only speak for American English, but your construction ("I feel itchy on my nose") would sound idiosyncratic in my country. "My X is/are itchy" is the usual